# Searching for string using OpenFileDialog and Multiselect

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing an exercise where I need to find a string in a group of files.

I manage to find the string selecting each file individually.
How can I do the same selecting all files at once.

```
openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
string filename = openFileDialog.SafeFileName;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
String s;
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(s.Contains("Specified string"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filename + " Contains the Specified string");
            break;
        }
    }

}
fs.Close();
sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenFileDialog has properties ([FileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx), [SafeFileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames.aspx)) that return all selected files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use [SafeFileNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames.aspx):

```
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach(string filename = openFileDialog.SafeFileName)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        String s;

            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(s.Contains("Specified string"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(filename + " Contains the Specified string");
                    break;
                }
            }

        fs.Close();
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

For second, you can use [Parallel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) for simultaneous processing of the files.